# Why registering a generic type with one type parameter to Unity Container fails here?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, unity-container, enterprise-library

I am trying to register a generic type to unitycontainer via configuration file, as shown below in a simplified way.

However on the LoadConfiguration method call I get an error:

*"The type name or alias IDataLoader`1[Bar] could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name."*

This is the line I get my exception after:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();
```

And those are my classes (in the assemblies same name as namespaces):

```
namespace FooBar.DataManager
{
    public interface IDataLoader<TSource>
    {
        void DoSomeWork(TSource source);
    }
}

namespace FooBar.DataManager.MyDataManager
{
    public class FooDataLoader : IDataLoader <Bar>
    {
      public void DoSomeWork(Bar source)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing {0}", source.Name);
      }
    }
}

namespace FooBar.DomainModel
{
    public class Bar
    {
        string Name {get; set;}
    }

}
```

And this is the part how I register in the configuration file:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
        <alias alias="Bar" type="FooBar.DomainModel.Bar, FooBar.DomainModel" />
        <alias alias="IDataLoader`1" type="FooBar.DataManager.IDataLoader, FooBar.DataManager" />

    <container>
      <register type="IDataLoader`1[Bar]" mapTo="FooBar.DataManager.MyDataManager.DataLoader, FooBar.DataManager.MyDataManager" name="FooBarLoader" />
    </container>

</unity>
```

Can you please advise how should I register the IDataLoader  generic type into unitycontainer? Or where I do my mistake?
Thanks!

Comment: Your alias appears to try to alias a non-generic `IDataLoader` type. Have you tried `<alias alias="IDataLoader'1" type="FooBar.DataManager.IDataLoader'1, FooBar.DataManager" />` ? (But with backticks instead of apostrophes... I can never get them to work in comments here...)

Comment: Hi Jon, yes I tried that.I am suspicious with the syntax whether I use it correctly or not to be honest. But I cannot see mistake.

Comment: Looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507491(v=pandp.30).aspx, I don't think you should have the backticks *anywhere*, in fact. It's not clear how aliases work with generics though... (As an aside, I haven't used Unity myself - if you're able to put together a short but *complete* example that we could easily use to reproduce the problem, that'd be great.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507491(v=pandp.30).aspx) again, I think you want to use backticks or square brackets for the *open* type in the alias target, but not for the *closed* type or the alias itself:

```xml
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="Bar" type="FooBar.DomainModel.Bar, FooBar.DomainModel" />
    <alias alias="IDataLoader" type="FooBar.DataManager.IDataLoader`1, FooBar.DataManager" />

    <container>
      <register type="IDataLoader[Bar]" mapTo="FooBar.DataManager.MyDataManager.DataLoader, FooBar.DataManager.MyDataManager" name="FooBarLoader" />
    </container>
</unity>
```

Comment: Jon, did you put the backtick end of the assembly name by purpose? (FooBar.DataManager`1) Does not that remarks the generic type and the number of parameters that is bound to type, but not the assembly?

Comment: @pencilCake: Nope, that was a stupid typo - fixed now, thanks. Whether it helps will be a different matter...

Comment: @jlvaquero: Sorry, I don't quite understand your comment. Your other answer suggests that alias is just a string replacement - I don't believe it is.